# Two different queries on the same table with the same WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have two different queries. But they are both on the same table and have both the same `WHERE` clause. So they are selecting the same row.

Query 1:

```
SELECT HOUR(timestamp), COUNT(*) as hits 
FROM hits_table 
WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE() 
GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp)
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*) as hits 
FROM hits_table 
WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY country
```

How can I make this more efficient?

Comment: in what way do you think that is inefficient?

Comment: I don't know but they are both fetching exactly the same columns.

Comment: Custom code will *never ever* beat a database doing a straight `WHERE` filter on an indexed field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this table is indexed correctly, it honestly doesn't matter how big the entire table is because you're only looking at today's rows.

If the table is indexed incorrectly the performance of these queries will be terrible no matter what you do.

Your `WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE()` clause means you need to have an index on the `timestamp` column.  In one of your queries the `GROUP BY country` shows that a compound covering index on `(timestamp, country)` will be a great help.

So, a single compound index `(timestamp, country)` will satisfy both the queries in your question.

Let's explain how that works. To look for today's records (or indeed any records starting and ending with particular `timestamp` values) and group them by country, and count them, MySQL can satisfy the query by doing these steps:

1. random-access the index to the first record that matches the `timestamp`. O(log n).
2. grab the first `country` value *from the index*.
3. scan to the next `country` value *in the index* and count.  O(n).
4. repeat step three until the end of the `timestamp` range.

This index scan operation is about as fast as a team of ace developers (the MySQL team) can get it to be with a decade of hard work. (You may not be able to outdo them on a Saturday afternoon.)  MySQL satisfies the whole query with a small subset of the index, so it doesn't really matter how big the table behind it is.

If you run one of these queries right after the other, it's possible that MySQL will still have some or all the index data blocks in a RAM cache, so it might not have to re-fetch them from disk. That will help even more.

Do you see how your example queries lead with `timestamp`? The most important `WHERE` criterion chooses a timestamp range. That's why the compound index I suggested has `timestamp` as its first column. If you don't have any queries that lead with `country` your simple index on that column probably is useless.

You asked whether you really need compound covering indexes. You probably should [read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) [about](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/range-optimization.html) [how](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/19/multi-column-indexes-vs-index-merge/) they work and make that decision for yourself.

There's obviously a tradeoff in choosing indexes. Each index slows the process of `INSERT` and `UPDATE` a little, and can speed up queries a lot. Only you can sort out the tradeoffs for your particular application.

Comment: This is an awesome answer! 
In the table I store visits. I have normal separate index on timestamp and country. I am not sure if I should also use compound index. I have also other columns which I want to count like Query 2. For example: Browser, Window resolution and language. The table does get alot of INSERT (every visitor) and UPDATE (for example if I want to store visit duration etc.) queries.

Comment: @OllieJones "a compound covering index on (timestamp, country) will be a great help." no it will not be - timestamps are 'likely' to be unique, meaning that this index doesn't add anything by sub-sorting on country if there's nothing to sub-sort. An extra index on `country, timestamp` might. You also say "it honestly doesn't matter how big the entire table is because you're only looking at today's rows" which is also not true *by definition* since I can name quite a few sites getting 1m+ hits per day.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, your assertion is contrary to my experience. Don't forget that MySQL indexes are BTREE -- that is, inherently ordered.

Comment: Now I am confused. Should I add a index `(timestamp, country)` or `(country, timestamp)` or no compound index at all. As I said I simply store (unique) hits in this table. I use this counter for many different sites. Per day it actually adds about 1m entries. The table does get queried hourly for today reports by user. For other reports I use daily generated reports which are added to the archive table.

Comment: `(timestamp,country)` is the correct covering index, as my answer says. I believe, with respect, that Mr. @NielsKeurentjes doesn't quite understand how index scans work and has written something incorrect in his recent comment.

Comment: Given my 15 years of professional experience as a database architect I do tend to know the odd thing about databases and index scans. And as such I also know that, as explained very clearly on the page you linked (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html), compound indexes are sorted left-to-right and as such extra columns have no use when they don't provide further specificity on a previous column. Therefore `timestamp,country` is identical in practical use to `timestamp`, assuming the timestamps are unique, which they nearly always are.

Answer (score 0):

Since both queries have different `GROUP BY` clauses they are inherently different and cannot be combined. Assuming there already is an index present on the `timestamp` field there is no straightforward way to make this more efficient.

If the dataset is huge (10 million or more rows) you *might* get a little extra efficiency out of making an extra combined index on `country, timestamp`, but that's unlikely to be measurable, and the lack of it will usually be mitigated by in-memory buffering of MySQL itself if these 2 queries are executed directly after another.

Comment: Ok, what if I would fetch in one query all results without `GROUP BY` and then go through this array myself? The dataset is huge.

Comment: I agree with the first paragraph. Without further details, the queries seem fine. I disagree with the second paragraph, though. A compound index allows what MySQL calls "Tight Index Scan" to process the GROUP BY clause http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html which is a *lot* quicker than using a temporary table even for smaller sets. I think a tight index scan is capable of counting rows as well, but haven't tested.

Comment: @Hazzit I'm aware of that optimization, that's why I suggest it - I just highly doubt it will improve more than a few ms unless there are millions of rows, and it might depend more on server config (RAM and MySQL config for index buffers etc.) than anything else how much it improves.

Comment: @yoshi emulating in generic code what a database is terribly good at (specifically: managing and processing large datasets) is, for straightforward tasks, rarely ever more efficient. Also, it's not like we're ever going to be able to give a definitive answer on it - it depends more on your data and config than anything else. Go try and compare if the performance is currently problematic, otherwise just accept that huge datasets don't always return instant results.

Comment: Ok. Another question if I add `LIMIT` to the query like this `GROUP BY country LIMIT 10` will it improve the perfomance?

Comment: Adding a `LIMIT` clause isn't going to help much. Your  `COUNT(*)` column requires processing all rows anyways. The trick is to have MySQL work on the *index* exclusively and never touch the actual database row. If you want more help, it might be a good idea to add your index definitions and MySQL's `EXPLAIN` info to your initial question.

Comment: @Hazzit and @Niels, the compound index should be `(timestamp, country)` for these queries. And yes, index scans can `count(*)`.

Comment: @OllieJones Thanks for pointing out the correct order for the compound index. I hadn't even noticed that Niels' index was the other way round. And thanks for confirming what I thought to be true about MySQL's index scans with regard to the COUNT() aggregate function. I wonder if that's documented anywhere.

Comment: Please read the comments on the other answer. The answer by @OllieJones is wrong on many counts, most specifically the column order. This is regrettably one of the many cases where StackOverflow rewards the most elaborate answers, no matter how wrong, over the concise correct answer, just because they sound likely to the untrained topicstarter.